# Regex matching between two strings python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match all ocurrences between two `[Term]`'s or a `[Term]` and a `[Typedef]` in a file cointaining something like this:

```
remark: Includes Ontology(OntologyID(OntologyIRI(<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/go/never_in_taxon.owl>))) [Axioms: 18 Logical Axioms: 0]
ontology: go

[Term]
id: GO:0000001
name: mitochondrion inheritance
namespace: biological_process
def: "The distribution of mitochondria, including the mitochondrial genome, into daughter cells after mitosis or meiosis, mediated by interactions between mitochondria and the cytoskeleton." [GOC:mcc, PMID:10873824, PMID:11389764]
synonym: "mitochondrial inheritance" EXACT []
is_a: GO:0048308 ! organelle inheritance
is_a: GO:0048311 ! mitochondrion distribution

[Term]
id: GO:0000002
name: mitochondrial genome maintenance
namespace: biological_process
def: "The maintenance of the structure and integrity of the mitochondrial genome; includes replication and segregation of the mitochondrial chromosome." [GOC:ai, GOC:vw]
is_a: GO:0007005 ! mitochondrion organization

[Term]
id: GO:0000011
name: vacuole inheritance
namespace: biological_process
def: "The distribution of vacuoles into daughter cells after mitosis or meiosis, mediated by interactions between vacuoles and the cytoskeleton." [GOC:mcc, PMID:10873824, PMID:14616069]
is_a: GO:0007033 ! vacuole organization
is_a: GO:0048308 ! organelle inheritance

[Typedef]
id: positively_regulates
name: positively regulates
namespace: external
xref: RO:0002213
holds_over_chain: negatively_regulates negatively_regulates
is_a: regulates ! regulates
transitive_over: part_of ! part of

[Typedef]
id: regulates
name: regulates
namespace: external
xref: RO:0002211
is_transitive: true
transitive_over: part_of ! part of
```

With: `(?=\[Term\]\s)[\s\S]*(?=\s\s\[Term\]\s)` I'm only matching between the first `[Term]` and the penultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
r'(?m)^\[Term].*(?:\r?\n(?!\[(?:Typedef|Term)]).*)*'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/chozOP/1)

**Details**

- `(?m)` - multiline modifier
- `^` - start of a line
- `\[Term]` - a `[Term]` substring
- `.*` - rest of the current line
- `(?:\r?\n(?!\[(?:Typedef|Term)]).*)*` - 0 or more occurrences of:

  - `\r?\n(?!\[(?:Typedef|Term)])` - a line break (CRLF or LF) not followed with a `[Typedef]` or `[Term]` substring
  - `.*` - rest of the current line

[Python code](https://ideone.com/62iola):

```
import re
s = """remark: Includes Ontology(OntologyID(OntologyIRI(<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/go/never_in_taxon.owl>))) [Axioms: 18 Logical Axioms: 0]
ontology: go

[Term]
id: GO:0000001
name: mitochondrion inheritance
namespace: biological_process
def: "The distribution of mitochondria, including the mitochondrial genome, into daughter cells after mitosis or meiosis, mediated by interactions between mitochondria and the cytoskeleton." [GOC:mcc, PMID:10873824, PMID:11389764]
synonym: "mitochondrial inheritance" EXACT []
is_a: GO:0048308 ! organelle inheritance
is_a: GO:0048311 ! mitochondrion distribution

[Term]
id: GO:0000002
name: mitochondrial genome maintenance
namespace: biological_process
def: "The maintenance of the structure and integrity of the mitochondrial genome; includes replication and segregation of the mitochondrial chromosome." [GOC:ai, GOC:vw]
is_a: GO:0007005 ! mitochondrion organization

[Term]
id: GO:0000011
name: vacuole inheritance
namespace: biological_process
def: "The distribution of vacuoles into daughter cells after mitosis or meiosis, mediated by interactions between vacuoles and the cytoskeleton." [GOC:mcc, PMID:10873824, PMID:14616069]
is_a: GO:0007033 ! vacuole organization
is_a: GO:0048308 ! organelle inheritance

[Typedef]
id: positively_regulates
name: positively regulates
namespace: external
xref: RO:0002213
holds_over_chain: negatively_regulates negatively_regulates
is_a: regulates ! regulates
transitive_over: part_of ! part of

[Typedef]
id: regulates
name: regulates
namespace: external
xref: RO:0002211
is_transitive: true
transitive_over: part_of ! part of"""
rx = r'(?m)^\[Term].*(?:\r?\n(?!\[(?:Typedef|Term)]).*)*'
cnt=0
for m in re.findall(rx, s):
    print(m)
    print('-------------- Next match ---------------')
    cnt = cnt + 1

print("Number of mathes: {}".format(cnt))
```

Output:

```
[Term]
id: GO:0000001
name: mitochondrion inheritance
namespace: biological_process
def: "The distribution of mitochondria, including the mitochondrial genome, into daughter cells after mitosis or meiosis, mediated by interactions between mitochondria and the cytoskeleton." [GOC:mcc, PMID:10873824, PMID:11389764]
synonym: "mitochondrial inheritance" EXACT []
is_a: GO:0048308 ! organelle inheritance
is_a: GO:0048311 ! mitochondrion distribution

-------------- Next match ---------------
[Term]
id: GO:0000002
name: mitochondrial genome maintenance
namespace: biological_process
def: "The maintenance of the structure and integrity of the mitochondrial genome; includes replication and segregation of the mitochondrial chromosome." [GOC:ai, GOC:vw]
is_a: GO:0007005 ! mitochondrion organization

-------------- Next match ---------------
[Term]
id: GO:0000011
name: vacuole inheritance
namespace: biological_process
def: "The distribution of vacuoles into daughter cells after mitosis or meiosis, mediated by interactions between vacuoles and the cytoskeleton." [GOC:mcc, PMID:10873824, PMID:14616069]
is_a: GO:0007033 ! vacuole organization
is_a: GO:0048308 ! organelle inheritance

-------------- Next match ---------------
Number of mathes: 3
```

Comment: This dont match the first `[Term]` and match the `[Typedef]`'s

Comment: @DiegoSilvera See https://regex101.com/r/chozOP/1/ Is your input exactly the same as you posted? Can there be leading whitespace on the lines with `[Typedef]` / `[Term]`?

Comment: @DiegoSilvera See https://ideone.com/62iola - there are 5 matches. Just as many as there are blocks in the text in the question.

Comment: Sorry, `[Term]`'s are OK, but `[Typedef]`'s shoudn't be matched. But changing the first `[(?:Typedef|Term)]` by `[(?:Term)]` works

Comment: @DiegoSilvera, I see, I will adjust the answer. You just need to keep `\[Term]` there. No need for a non-capturing group if there is no alternation nor quantifier.

Answer (score 1):

To match between the two, you can try this:

```
import re
s = "[Term] id: GO:0000001 name: mitochondrion inheritance namespace: biological_process def: "The distribution of mitochondria, including the mitochondrial genome, into daughter cells after mitosis or meiosis, mediated by interactions between mitochondria and the cytoskeleton." [GOC:mcc, PMID:10873824, PMID:11389764] synonym: "mitochondrial inheritance" EXACT [] is_a: GO:0048308 ! organelle inheritance is_a: GO:0048311 ! mitochondrion distribution" #etc
the_data = re.findall("\[Term\](.*?)\n\s\[Term\]|\[Term\](.*?)\n\s\[Typedef\]", s)
```

Final Output:

```
[(' id: GO:0000001 name: mitochondrion inheritance namespace: biological_process def: "The distribution of mitochondria, including the mitochondrial genome, into daughter cells after mitosis or meiosis, mediated by interactions between mitochondria and the cytoskeleton." [GOC:mcc, PMID:10873824, PMID:11389764] synonym: "mitochondrial inheritance" EXACT [] is_a: GO:0048308 ! organelle inheritance is_a: GO:0048311 ! mitochondrion distribution', ''), ('', ' id: GO:0000011 name: vacuole inheritance namespace: biological_process def: "The distribution of vacuoles into daughter cells after mitosis or meiosis, mediated by interactions between vacuoles and the cytoskeleton." [GOC:mcc, PMID:10873824, PMID:14616069] is_a: GO:0007033 ! vacuole organization is_a: GO:0048308 ! organelle inheritance')]
```

Comment: I do this: `file_object  = open(file_path, 'r')
data = re.findall("\[Term\](.*?)\n\s\[Term\]|\[Term\](.*?)\n\s\[Typedef\]", file_object.read())` and get an empty list

Comment: @DiegoSilvera make sure that the text paragraphs in your file are separated by one blank line. The regex I put in my answer checks that first, there is a newline, and second, that there is a blank line, `\s`. I ran the regex on the content that you posted, and it worked for me. Try removing the `\s` is the regex and let me know if that works.